# Why does the SHOW FULL COLUMNS command show the Type field in lower case?

Tags: mysql, schema, table

When I run `SHOW FULL COLUMNS`, it shows the Type column in lower case, such as `text` and `varchar(255)`.  I thought these type names were supposed to be upper case (`TEXT` and `VARCHAR`), per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-types.html.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it is sloppiness on the part of the implementor.

Keywords are not case sensitive.  A common convention, except by some `SHOW` commands, is to use uppercase.

Column names are not case sensitive.

Table and database names may be case sensitive, primarily dependent on the OS.